# Batch request with fql using javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook-fql, facebook-javascript-sdk

The following batch request for retrieve friends using the same app is not working:

```
var search = {batch: [
    {
      'name' : 'getFriends',
      'relative_url': 'method/fql.query?query=SELECT+uid,+first_name,+name,+pic_square,+pic_small+FROM+user+WHERE+is_app_user=1+and+uid+IN+(SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=' + userId + ')'
    },
    {
      'method': 'get',
      'relative_url': '{result=getFriends:$.data[*].uid}/news.reads/article', 
    }
]};
```

and the following code executes the batch request:

```
FB.api('/', 'post', search, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

but the first search returns **null**. What's wrong with the query?

According to facebook documentation for batch requests, the *relative_url* is

> (...) a relative_url (the portion of the URL after graph.facebook.com)

get from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/).

So I changed the first block of code to:

```
var search = {batch: [
    {
        'name' : 'getFriends',
        'method' : 'GET',
        'relative_url': 'method/fql?q=SELECT uid, first_name, name, pic_square, pic_small FROM user WHERE is_app_user=1 and uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())'
    },
    {
        'method': 'GET',
        'relative_url': '{result=getAmigos:$.data[*].uid}/news.reads/article'
    }
]};
```

the **relative_url** of the first block on the batch works at Open Graph API Tool at facebook, but at the JS the http code is 500 and the message body is:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Graph batch API does not allow REST API method fql",
        "type": "FacebookApiException",
        "code": 3
    }
}
```

but in the api batch requests documentation allows fql queries. The documentation is outdated? Should I open a bug?

P.S: the fql without the batch request is

```
SELECT uid, first_name, name, pic_square, pic_small 
FROM user WHERE is_app_user=1 
     and uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's working now. I just add the `access_token` parameter at the batch object. like this:

```
var searchArgs = {
   access_token: FB.getAuthResponse().access_token,
   batch: []
};

searchArgs.batch.push({
     'method': 'GET',
     'name': 'amigosapp',
     'relative_url': 'method/fql.query?query=SELECT+uid,+first_name,+name,+pic_square,+pic_small+FROM+user+WHERE+is_app_user=1+and+uid+IN+(SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me())&limit=20',
     'omit_response_on_success': false
});

searchArgs.batch.push({
     'method': 'GET',
     'relative_url': 'news.reads/article?date_format=U&ids={result=amigosapp:$.[*].uid}'
});
```

the other trick was use the **jsonpath** expression in a different way. I couldn't make the second request for each user of the first request. So I changed the way to get it adding the friends ids at the end of the graph api request. I think that my first thought about a request per friend it's not possible using the batch request.

Then I did the call of the batch:

```
FB.api('/', 'POST', searchArgs,
    function(response) {
        var friends = response[0].body;
        console.log(friends);
        var activities = response[1].body;
        console.log(activities);
    }
);
```

Now it's just organize the posts retrieved.

[]'s

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `method/fql`; Facebook's FQL endpoint is now just `fql`.

```
...
"name": "getFriends",
"method": "GET",
"relative_url": "fql?q=SELECT...",
...
```